# Use my own unapproved plug-in with PhoneGap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Does PhoneGap Build allow me to use my own plug-in (on my own git).  Or do ALL plug-ins that you use need to be public and approved?

Comment: you can't, you should switch to local development to use your own plugins and build the app yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you asking about the PhoneGap Build online service, you cannot load your own plugins without submitting and making them public.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own plugin and use it without permission from any one else. You do not have to share your plugin. If you decide to open source it then others may find and use it as well.

For more information on writing PhoneGap plugins: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html

Comment: he is talking about phonegap build service, you can't use private/unapproved plugins there